# UIImageView stretched even after setting content mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a simple project where I have a image that needs to be put into a viewcontroller and then added to the main view. The code works fine, but even though the content mode has been set `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`  , I don't see the image scaled correctly. It appears stretched and clipped. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.jpg"]];
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [controller.view addSubview:imgView];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
}
```

Comment: sare you adding the image completly in code? have you checked your IB for incase that the image is may be set to aspect fit in the IB?

Comment: No there is no UI. This is all via code. This is just a simple view controller app.

Comment: is this a background image?

Comment: no its a image put into a imageview, then loaded into a viewcontroller via code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problm by creating a view using storyboard, linking it via IBOutlets and then loading the image. For whatever reason, assigning the imageview in the above mentioned way does not change its properties once set.

Comment: Why don't you try to accept your own answer ?? So that it wont listed in Unanswered Question.